# Nuxtjs 3, Apollo, GraphQL | TypeError: _super.call is not a function

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-client, strapi, nuxtjs3

I have some trouble with my Nuxt site. I want to load data from Strapi (cms) with using graphql. But i've got some errors:  TypeError: _super.call is not a function.[image: screenshot of the browser] [image: Visual code node development error]

The error pops up when i going to generate my site and when i refresh my site. It shows the content normally at the first load.

```js
<template>
  <section>
    <NavBar />
    <p>dsfsdfsdfsdf</p>
      <section v-if="websiteOptimaalNieuws.data" :key="websiteOptimaalNieuws.data[0].attributes.slug" class="Nieuwspagina">
        
        <h1>{{ websiteOptimaalNieuws.data[0].attributes.Titel }}</h1>
        
        {{ websiteOptimaalNieuws.data[0].attributes.Artikel }}
      </section>
    <Contactform />
    <Footer />
  </section>
</template>

<script>
import gql from 'graphql-tag'
import NavBar from '../../components/NavBar/NavBar.vue';
import Footer from '../../components/Footer.vue';
import Contactform from '../../components/Contactform.vue';

const SINGLE_NIEUWS_QUERY = gql`
query ($slug:String){
  websiteOptimaalNieuws(filters:{slug:{eq:$slug}}){
    data {
      id,
      attributes {
        Titel,
        slug,
        Artikel,
      }
    }
  }
}
`

export default {
    async asyncData({ app, params }) {
        const client = app.apolloProvider.defaultClient;
        const { slug } = params;
        const res = await client.query({
            query: SINGLE_NIEUWS_QUERY,
            variables: {
                slug,
            },
        });
        const { websiteOptimaalNieuws } = res.data;
        return {
          websiteOptimaalNieuws,
        };
    },
    components: { NavBar, Footer, Contactform }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
 .Nieuwspagina {
  padding-top: 100px;
 }
</style>
```